# How can I make the objective-c compiler assume undeclared properties are dynamic?

Tags: objective-c, properties, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I'd like to be able to write

```
id foo = [MyObject new];
foo.bar = [NSObject new];
```

But I get the following error:

```
/blah/blah/blah/Blah.m:32:9: error: property 'bar' not found on object of type '__strong id'
foo.bar = [NSObject new];
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Since clang doesn't report a warning I could suppress, I assume this behavior is permanent, but I hope someone can tell me otherwise.

Obviously, I know this will break by default, but I plan to use [Dynamic Method Resolution](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtDynamicResolution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH102-SW1) to make it work.

Comment: Do you have a `bar` property declared in the `MyObject` header?

Comment: No. I want to be able to use dynamic method resolution to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the dot syntax on a generic object pointer like this.

The reason is that the compiler rewrites `foo.bar = baz;` to `[foo setBar:baz]`, but since you can change the setter's name, `@property (strong, nonatomic, setter=setListOfApples:) NSArray * listOfOranges;`, it *must* be able to see the property declaration.

If you use the standard message send syntax, this will work. In other words, you have to either tell the compiler the exact type of the object so that it can look up the property's setter, or tell it the exact setter name you want it to use.

Comment: Thanks! That all makes perfect sense.

Answer (score -2):

Would @dynamic take care of it?

@dynamic foo;
@dynamic bar;